# How to import Python Markdown and pygments when developing Sublime Text plugins?

Tags: python, sublimetext2, markdown, pygments

I copied `markdown` and `pygments` folder to my plugin's path, and did this:

```py
try: 
    import sys
    sys.path.append("./markdown")
    sys.path.append("./pygments")
    import markdown

except ImportError:
    self.view.insert(edit, 0, "The markdown package wasn't imported.")
```

And this doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like any other Python program, if you put the `markdown` and `pygments` files/folders into your plugin's ***folder***, you should be able to import them with no problem. For example, make your directory structure like so:

```
Packages/
    |
    |-MyPlugin/
        |
        |-my_plugin.py
        |
        |-markdown.py
        |
        |-pygments/
            |
            |-__init__.py
            |
            |- etc.
```

then in `my_plugin.py` you should be able to have:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import markdown
import pygments

class MyPluginCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    # and so on...
```

This also makes your plugin much easier to distribute later on, as everything is self-contained. Obviously, make sure you are using Python 2.6-compatible versions of any third-party libraries.

Comment: My file structure is exactly like what you said, except the `markdown` is a folder. And when I tried to import, it throughs an `ImportError`.

Comment: @dyzdyz010 - what is the full text of the `ImportError`?

Comment: I only saw it printed exception:Import Error... Now I know where the problem is - every time I restart the Sublime, only if I build the plugin who imported the two packages, or it comes the `ImportError`. However, I don't know how to deal with this...